# how to set the ranges of coordinates X & Y for observation window geometry in spatstat package in R

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, spatstat, r-ppp

Hi? I have a data of seedlings distribution which contains species types, X and Y coordinates in UTM. I want to create a point pattern by their X & Y coordinate location with the help of ppp() function in spatstat package.  I tried it with following 2 ways:

```
 p.patt <- ppp(mydata$X, mydata$Y)
 p.patt <- ppp(mydata$X, mydata$Y, owin(c(100,131), c(100,130)))
```

But there is a “Warning message: 435 points were rejected as lying outside the specified window” for both of them.

I guess this is related to ranges of X and Y coordinates that should be specified in this code in c(…), c(…). I checked the range of X &Y and R gave me following ranges:

```
for X: 368615 and 368746, 
for Y: 4587355 and 4587485
```

When I plot the data, a shape of the plot looks like "tilted rombo". I don't know if it is help.

Here I have just randomly chosen tried some numbers: 100 & 131 & 130. I couldn’t find any information how to set them online.

So my question is how I can use these ranges of coordinates to set observation window geometry of point patterm in spatstat package in R?.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in the `owin` call are not the width and height of the window; they are the `X` and `Y` coordinates of the corners of the window.

Since the range of `X` coordinate values of the data points is from 368615 to 368746, the window needs to contain this range, at least. Similarly the range of `Y` values must be contained in the window. The minimal window that will not give a warning is

```
p.patt <- ppp(mydata$X, mydata$Y, owin(c(368615,368746), c(4587355,4587485)))
```

or equivalently

```
p.patt <- ppp(mydata$X, mydata$Y, c(368615,368746), c(4587355,4587485))
```

But this is just the minimal window that is acceptable; for a proper analysis, you need information about the survey region. If it is not a rectangle then, as Ege says, you need to specify `owin(poly=...)` using the coordinate locations of the vertices of the polygon.

Comment: it works well. Now I got it. I'll consider Edge and your suggestion about corners of survey region. Thank you very much for both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have information about the plot? E.g. the coordinates of the corners of a polygonal region delimiting the plot? If you have these coordinates use them as input in the argument `poly` of `owin`. See the help file for `owin` for details. In lack of any information you can try `ripras` to estimate the boundary of the plot.

What you do right now is to say that you define a point pattern in the rectangle [0,131]×[0,130] and then you provide a bunch of points with coordinates outside this area (much larger coordinate values) and they are all discarded.

Comment: @ Ege Rubak. Unfortunately I don't have info about them. Can you tell me what is the most important thing to consider to set it?